# Laravel AdminLTE pass parameter to menu can method

Tags: laravel, adminlte

I am currently using
https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE for my laravel project. The problem I am facing is that I am trying to pass a parameter to the can method in the menu configuration as seen below but haven't gotten any luck to get it to work.

Menu Config:

```
[
    'text' => 'Add new post',
    'url'  => 'admin/blog/new',
    'can'  => ['access:posts'],
],
```

The posts gate:

```
Gate::define('access', function ($user,$location) {
   return $user->hasAccess($location);
});
```

I think i might be passing the parameter to the gate incorrectly.

Comment: You are missing a dollar sign here: `$user->hasAccess(location)`, it should be `$user->hasAccess($location)`

Comment: That was a typo the problem is that the access gate is not receiving the parameter from the can method

Comment: I may be wrong but looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/blob/master/src/Menu/Filters/GateFilter.php#L51), it looks like you can't pass additional arguments to `can` in a menu configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass additional argument.

But if you just want to bypass variable you can do using `use`. An example you can define based URL segment/path.

```
$location = request()->segment(1); // get 'blog' from admin/blog/new
Gate::define('access', function ($user) use($location) {
   return $user->hasAccess($location);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For future Laravel-AdminLTE newcomers (like me):

Yes, you can pass a parameter to the Gate used by the 'can' option, but not in the same option, since a commit on [Sep 18, 2017](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/blob/2d6674686b7ed3176816eec7d3fe367d87ba21c4/src/Menu/Filters/GateFilter.php) ([here](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/blob/master/src/Menu/Filters/GateFilter.php) is the latest Laravel-AdminLTE v3.8.4, by the time of this answer, it has comments) there is an option called 'model' that is used as arguments for the Gate, you can use it as follow:

Menu item:

```
[
    'text'  => 'Add new post',
    'url'   => 'admin/blog/new',
    'can'   => 'access',
    'model' => 'posts',
],
```

Gate:

```
Gate::define('access', function ($user,$location) {
    return $user->hasAccess($location);
});
```

It will call 'access' Gate passing 'post' as argument.

GateFilter isAllowed source code from [second link](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/blob/master/src/Menu/Filters/GateFilter.php) above:

```
/**
     * Check if a menu item is allowed for the current user.
     *
     * @param  array  $item  A menu item
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isAllowed($item)
    {
        // Check if there are any permission defined for the item.

        if (empty($item['can'])) {
            return true;
        }

        // Read the extra arguments (a db model instance can be used).

        $args = isset($item['model']) ? $item['model'] : [];

        // Check if the current user can perform the configured permissions.

        if (is_string($item['can']) || is_array($item['can'])) {
            return $this->gate->any($item['can'], $args);
        }

        return true;
    }
```